# Optimising money in bonds

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Hi im doing an optimisation problem but dont understand what the terms mean.

Suppose someone wants to invest $\$110,000$.

They have $4$ choices as to  what they invest their money into:

$\bullet$ municipal bond yielding $6\%$,

$\bullet$ an industrial bond yielding $13\%$,

$\bullet$ Treasury bills at $10\%$,

$\bullet$ certificates of deposit (CDs) at $9\%$.

I want to maximise their annual interest (in dollars)

There are some constraints (which i havent typed) but i just want to know what these terms mean ie say they invest $\$27,500$ on each one, what would their annual interest be (in dollars) ?

Thank you

Comment: I think that if he puts m on municipal bonds , i  on industrial, t on treasury and c on CDs  then the annual interest would just be 6% of m + 13% of i + 10% of t + 9% of c ?

Comment: Reason for no constraints is that I want to solve the problem by myself, I just want to know how to calculate annual interest in dollars

Comment: I assume that the percentages in the question are interest rates per annum.  The objective function is $\max z = 0.06m + 0.13i + 0.1t + 0.09c$.